# Problem with a function in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I have a problem with this code:

```
function reimburse() payable external {
            require(msg.sender == borrower, 'only borrower can reimburse');
            require(msg.value = amount + interest, 'borrower need to reimburse exactly amount + interest');
            _transitionTo(State.CLOSED);
            lender.transfer(amount + interest);
        }
```

When I compile it in remix, it shows 2 errors which are below:

-TypeError: Expression has to be an lvalue

-TypeError: No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup

I really don't understand.
Could someone help me to fix these problems please?

Thank you very much

Take care

Answer (score 0):

This `==` is an equality operator - it checks whether both sides are equal.

This `=` is an assignment operator - it assigns whatever variable is on the left-hand side to whatever is on the right-hand side.

This line:

```
require(msg.value = amount + interest, 'borrower need to reimburse exactly amount + interest');
```

...should be doing an equality check. You need to change `=` to `==`.

(For the second error, it's not clear what the issue is without seeing the rest of the code.)

Comment: Thank you so much.
It solved both problems.